# What happens if the response to the commit from the database is not received?

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

If I have method with `@Transaction`(with default isolation level) and after all it send `commit` to DB, DB set transaction's visible for other and send response back to me, but network is lagging and I receive timeout. What happens? Transaction will be rollbacked?

Comment: No, the transaction will be kept open until the database connection is closed/lost. That will result in an implicit rollback.

Comment: The data will remain committed, and your app won't know about it. As simple as that.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I mean database received commit, but we didn't receive answer on commit call

Comment: @TheImpaler but how then i can guarantee that something happened or not happened(how to guarantee consistency)?

Comment: When you lost the database connection after a successful commit, but before receiving the confirmation of the commit, the transaction has been committed successfully. Just connect again and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `COMMIT` statement times out, the client cannot be certain whether the transaction was committed or not. It could have been committed successfully, but the network broke when sending the response to the client, or the `COMMIT` statement could have been canceled by the timeout.

If that worries you, you could get the transaction ID while the transaction is in progress:

```
SELECT pg_current_xact_id();
```

Then, after the timeout, you can run

```
SELECT pg_xact_status(123456);
```

to see if that transaction was committed or not (replace 123456 with the result from the first query).

In most cases, `COMMIT` is a very fast an unproblematic operation, and it shouldn't give you trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the [Chapter 17. Transaction management](https://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/transaction.html) of the Spring Framework, in general, if a transaction times out, it will be rolled back.

In the case of using Spring with a Postgresql database, when using the `@Transactional` annotation with a timeout parameter, if the database operation takes longer than the specified timeout period, a [`TransactionTimedOutException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionTimedOutException.html) will be thrown and the transaction will be rolled back .

After looking at the comments under the original question, if the database receives the commit but the client does not receive a response due to a network issue, the transaction will still be committed on the database side. The client may receive a timeout error, but the transaction will have been successfully committed on the database

I also recommend this [article](https://www.cubrid.org/blog/3826470) as it dives deep into how timeouts work.

Comment: That is not what the poster asked about though, is it? In their scenario the database has already committed.

Answer (score -1):

Typically, when you send a request to the database the transaction is started. During this time, the changes made within the transaction are not visible to other transactions until it is committed or rolled back.

If there is a network issue the transaction may remain in an open state on the database side. It will eventually close the connection due to inactivity or reach a timeout limit. After the connection is closed, the transaction will be automatically rolled back.

Comment: Again. Not what the poster described in their question. Misleading answers are worse than no answer at all.